# Do I have to use PHP if I am running a WAMP/MAMP/LAMP stack?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, mamp, lamp

If I want to use Ruby or Python or any other OOP language other than PHP while still running a WAMP/LAMP/MAMP stack so I can still use Windows/MySQL/Apache is that a good idea? Are there better stacks I should look into? And if this is ok to do, why isn't it called a WAM[choose-your-adventure] instead of a WAMP...?

Comment: Yes You Can Use Windows/MySQL/Apache or either you can use open source linux/MySQL/Apache

Comment: The `XAMP` stacks are just convenient installers that contain the necessary packages or precompiled binaries and configurations to deploy a basic web application/server. You can optionally disable, update or add-on to any of the individual services that the stacks provide. I suggest if you plan to run a different programming language, that you install the individual packages and configure as desired. As the stacks are usually pre-configured to support a specific environment, such as enabling `mod_php` in Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P does not stands for the PHP only (saying about all of them), it could also mean Python if you wish.

And all this is just words, till the moment you understand advantages and prospects of each.

So, the right question is what should you consider also.

I think you'd like LEMP (E stands for the Ngnix, for many projects it'd be better than Apache; yet, is totally disputable)

https://lemp.io/

Also, it's quite popular nowadays to use Node.js as a server (MEAN software bundle). Yet, it is totally different from what you are looking at, - whole bundle is either javascript, or js-based frameworks, as you can understand from the name of it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEAN_(software_bundle)

It is quite a big subject to dig in, - surf for it on the net. Main idea - you'd better understand deeply what lays beyond each bundle, so you can get, if it fits to your project, or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use Nginx for front http-server.

[Here is](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/configuring-nginx-on-your-web-server.html) a simple setup for Nginx with php-fpm, and example for [RoR application](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu).

Windows usually runs ASP.NET applications with IIS.

For your situation better to use Linux+Nginx+MariaDB+PHP-FPM